# How can I compute and initialize in init "content" property ? swift

Tags: swift, class, methods, properties

I am trying to initialize `content` property by using `setupForNewGame()` method where I passed two properties, but I want to use computed property, how can I do it?

```
class Grid{
   private var content: [[Int?]]
   init(width: Int, height: Int){
      content = Grid.setupForNewGame(width: width, height: height)
   }
   class func setupForNewGame(width: Int,height: Int)->[[Int]]{
      return ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create properties for `width` and `height` in `class Grid`. In the `init(width:height:)` set values for these properties.

Create `content` as ***computed property*** that `returns` the result of `setupForNewGame(width:height:)` method using the above created `width` and `height` properties.

```
class Grid {
    let width: Int
    let height: Int

    var content: [[Int]] { //this is a computed property.....
        return Grid.setupForNewGame(width: self.width, height: self.height)
    }

    init(width: Int, height: Int) {
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }

    class func setupForNewGame(width: Int, height: Int) -> [[Int]] {
        return ...
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let grid = Grid(width: 3, height: 3)
print(grid.content) //prints the result returned from `setupForNewGame(width:height:)` method using width = 3 and height = 3
```